# Network or shutdown issues on my Arch Pi

Tags: networking, archlinux, server, headless

I'm using a B board as a headless print/scan server with Cups installed on Arch. The pi is plugged into a linksys router with DHCP, but i'm using the "Reserve IP address" feature on the router to ensure it has a consistent IP address. I'm powering it with a Samsung 1A micro USB phone charger.

It works fine, but the problem is that after a long time has passed (overnight, or at the end of the day) the Pi doesn't seem to be connected. Normally, all the LEDs that should be on are on, but there isn't any blinking. I have no access to a screen, so I'm not sure how I can check if the Pi is even on at this stage, since it doesn't respond to pings or SSH and it doesn't seem to be on the Client table. At this point, I usually just unplug it and plug it back in and it works for another while, but obviously this isn't ideal. Any suggestions?

Comment: What kind of router do you use? Some are known to not work well with this "reserved IP address" feature. (My Archlinux-Pi shows the symptoms you describe with my fritzbox). Checking the logs after reboot should show whether the system froze or just lost connection...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a weak power supply or something running on the Arch that causes it to hang. Difficult to say. You need to inspect logs and try and work it out. Maybe the Pi itself is damaged?

You can use the **built in watchdog** to reset the Pi if it hangs though.

```
sudo apt-get install watchdog
```

Uncomment the following line in /etc/watchdog.conf

```
watchdog-device = /dev/watchdog
```

Edit /etc/modules

And add the following:

```
# hardware watchdog
bcm2708_wdog
```

Run the following command to activate the module and service:

```
sudo modprobe bcm2708_wdog
sudo service watchdog restart
```

The default settings are that if the Pi uses allot of resources during 1 minute period it will do a hard reset.

You can test with a fork bomb. Type this into the console. It should restart within  a minute. If it doesn't check the configuration.

```
: (){ :|:& };:
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks really useful, but I suppose I'll have to wait a couple of hours if it does the trick. For the logs you mentioned, as a semi-linux-noob, what should I be looking for/at?

Comment: Use the fork bomb to test. It will crash the Pi and you see if the auto reset works. Logs are in `/var/logs`  and also look in `/etc/syslog` file for other settings. IN Arch it might be slightly different I am not sure cause I don't use Artch.